# QML QtCreator reformats property of component type with invalid code

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have the following property defined, for example:

```
property Gradient greenGradient:  Gradient {
    GradientStop {
        position: 0.0
        color: "#00f03b"
    }
    GradientStop {
        position: 1.0
        color: "#3cb53b"
    }
}
```

In QtCreator (v3.5.0, running in Windows7) when I do a

> Tools->QML/JS->Reformat File

it changes my property to the following invalid code:

```
property Gradient greenGradient: greenGradient: Gradient {
                                     GradientStop {
                                         position: 0.0
                                         color: "#00f03b"
                                     }
                                     GradientStop {
                                         position: 1.0
                                         color: "#3cb53b"
                                     }
                                 }
```

Am I doing something incorrectly by defining a `Component` as a property like this?  Rhe QML docs [state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html):

> Additionally, any QML object type can be used as a property type. For example:
>
> `property Item someItem`
> `property Rectangle someRectangle`

Or is it just a bug in the QtCreator reformat function?  I tried a few different object types with the same result.  Basic types like `int`, `color`, `var`, `string` work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

The Qt5 docs are silent (or unclear at least) on this topic. However, in a Qt 4.7 doc I found [this](https://www.ics.com/files/qtdocs/qml-extending-types.html):

> Such object-type properties default to an undefined value.

So, the code would have to read like this instead:

```
property Gradient greenGradient
greenGradient: Gradient {
    GradientStop {
        position: 0.0
        color: "#00f03b"
    }
    GradientStop {
        position: 1.0
        color: "#3cb53b"
    }
}
```

It's worth nothing that both the original and the modified code *function the same*. The modified version just gets by the QtCreator reformat function without getting messed up.